# Why would one think that a solution of the time-independent Schrödinger equation is in the span of configuration state functions?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, pauli-exclusion-principle, quantum-chemistry

I am trying to understand why the hypothesis of configuration interaction methods is valid, i.e. I want to understand why one would think that an $N$-body wave function would be in the span of antisymmetric functions that are simultaneous eigenvectors of each operator that commutes with the hamiltonian (this is the fundamental idea of CI-methods, right?).

*Here is an attempt at an unfinished proof*: There is a variant of the spectral theorem that says that for every operator that commutes, there is a basis $\{f_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in J}$ for $L^2(\mathbb{R}^N)$ where each basis element is an eigenvector of every operator. Consider such a collection, but take a maximal collection of operators that commute with the hamiltonian that also commute with each other (a collection is called maximal if it is not contained in any strictly larger collection). The associated basis has the required properties if and only if it is antisymmetric. It is possible to form the antisymmetrization for each element
$$
\text{asym}(f_\alpha)(r_1,\cdots,r_N) = \sum_{P \in S_N} \text{sgn}(P)f_\alpha(r_{P(1)},\cdots,r_{P(N)}).
$$
It is clear to me that this is an eigenvector of the hamiltonian (as $[P,H] = 0$ always). Is this the basis I am looking for? I.e. is it still an eigenvector of every operator?

I would appreciate it if you could finish the proof.

Comment: The statement you are trying to prove is not true. For a spherically symmetric wavefunction, the $x$, $y$ and $z$ components of angular momentum all commute with the Hamiltonian, but not with each other. Consequently you can find a basis of simultaneous eigenstates of the Hamiltonian with any one of these operator, but there is no simultaneous eigenbasis for these 3 operators (let alone one that is also an eigenbasis of the Hamiltonian). You need to limit your attention to a set of operator all of which commute with each other (and in particular all of which commute with particle exchange)

Comment: @BySymmetry Thanks, I changed the question. Do you know CI (and why the theorem) should still be valid?